# Does the size of data types in C depend on the OS?

Tags: c, types

For example, `int` takes 4 bytes on a 32-bit OS, but 8 bytes on a 64-bit OS, does this kind of thing exist in C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. This is precisely what is meant by "platform-specific definitions" for things like the size of `int` and the meaning of system calls.

They depend not just on the OS, but also on the target hardware and compiler configuration.

Comment: can you verify your answer a little bit?!

how can it depend on the compiler and OS and target hardware at the same time

Comment: @ArmiaWagdy A computer with an x64 processor could run both a 32-bit and a 64-bit operating system (Win32 and Win8, let's say.) On top of that, a compiler on the 64-bit operating system could choose to define `long` as 32 bits (as visual studio does) or as 64 bits (as GCC) does. On top of that, you could have a compiler set to generate 32bit executables or 64bit executables.

Answer (score 3):

It can depend on the OS, but more typically it depends on the hardware. Many micro controllers still use 16-bit int:s, since this is what the device handles naturally.

While we're in the subject. This does not only affect the `int` type, it also affects how expressions are evaluated. The principle is that every expression is evaluated as though it would have been evaluated in `int` precision, or larger. For example, given two 16-bit `short` variables `a` and `b` and a `long` variable `x`, the expression `x = a*b` will yield different result depending on the size of `int`, even though none of the involved variables have the type `int`.

Comment: how can it depend on hardware? for example if I use AVR 8-bit the size of int will be 8 bit also

Comment: By "hardware" I mean the microcontroller used. In your case, an AVR typically use 16 bit (not 8) int:s, whereas an ARM use 32.

Answer (score 2):

C datatype sizes depend on the memory model implemented by the compiler.  Think in terms of ILP (Int, Long, Pointer), and the number of bits used for those specified.

So compilers using an ILP64 data model will have the Int, Long and Pointer all set to 64 bits.  But an LP64 data model will have the Int set to 32bits and the Long and Pointer set to 64 bits.

Compiler writers will try to use a data model that best fits the target platform.  But also have to take into consideration the difficulty of porting libraries, and compiling source code intended for a different data model.

You can easily see what data model you are using with the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                 
#define BYTE_SIZE 8

void main(void)
{

  int sizeof_int = sizeof(int) * BYTE_SIZE;
  int sizeof_long = sizeof(long) * BYTE_SIZE;
  int sizeof_ptr = sizeof(&sizeof_int) * BYTE_SIZE;

  printf("Size of int: %d, long: %d, pointer: %d\n",
         sizeof_int, sizeof_long, sizeof_ptr );
}
```

On my 64 bit AMD Pc running 64 bit Debian Squeeze, it shows that GCC is using and LP64 data model.  This data model is the most common 64 bit data model, as it was agreed to standardize on this by a number of major UNIX vendors in 1995.  They did this to aid the transition, ensure portability and interoperability and to maximize performance.

Comment: For increased portability, you could define `BYTE_SIZE` as `#define BYTE_SIZE CHAR_BIT` where `CHAR_BIT`, defined in `<limits.h>`, is precisely the number of bits per byte.